# “Zusammenhalt zwischen” or “zusammenhalt unter”?

Tags: difference, usage, preposition

I have seen both:

> Zusammenhalt *zwischen* xxx

and

> Zusammenhalt *unter* xxx

I can’t work out whether there is any difference in meaning/usage. Please explain.

Comment: I only know the first way.
In which context have you seen both?

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference in meaning but in usage:

If you mean the cohesion in a group you use *unter*:

> The cohesion among soldiers.
>
> Der Zusammenhalt unter den Soldaten

If you mean the cohesion between two persons or so you use *zwischen*:

> The cohesion between the two siblings.
>
> Der Zusammenhalt zwischen den beiden Geschwistern.

But (because you referring to a group):

> The cohesion among siblings.
>
> Der Zusammenhalt unter Geschwistern.

Comment: oder: "D. Z. zwischen Geschwistern". Oder Magneten. Oder Variablen.